# errorInfo of PDOStatement is not reset across queries

Tags: php, postgresql, pdo

PDOStatement::errorInfo() stays the same through several queries in the same PDO.

```
        try
        {
            $oReq = $this->_oPDO->prepare($sSqlQuery);
            $oReq->execute($aBindParams);
            $mRes = $oReq->fetchAll();

            if (!empty($oReq->errorInfo()[2])) // specific driver error
                throw new \PDOException($oReq->errorInfo()[2], $oReq->errorInfo()[0]);

            return $mRes;
        } catch (\PDOException $e)
        {
        }
```

This is the code in a method we will call execute, in a class initializing a PDO in its construct ($this->_PDO). If I execute it 2 times, and the first time fails and throws an error, it will also fail and throw on the 2nd passage with the same error even though the 2nd request is good, because the errorInfo() still has the error of the previous request.

The doc states that the PDOStatement::errorInfo() (here $oReq->errorInfo()) should give the error of the current statement. But it seems that if there are no errors, it just stays. And if there is a new error if will override the current one.

I tested the following for example:
Good req 1, bad req 1, bad req 2, good req 2 = fails on the good req 2 with the error of the bad req 2.

Is there something I should do to like reset the error of the PDOStatement when I find one, or it is something bad I do, or a bug in the PDO?

Comment: what's your setting for `PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES`? If it is set to `true`, set it to `falsse` and rerun your tests.

Comment: Why you're using unreliable errorInfo instead of PDOException?

Comment: I am using ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES to true but setting it to false didnt change anything (already tried it before this post). @YourCommonSense, what do you mean?

Comment: I mean in case of error, PDO can throw a PDOException by itself, no assistance required, thank you.

Comment: @YourCommonSense Ok it works properly with PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION option. I didn't know this one. I guess errorInfo isn't reliable like you said, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

PDOStatement::errorInfo not reliable; using PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION in PDO option worked for me. Thanks @YourCommonSense.